# Dataset that has approximately 1% missing values completely at random?

Tags: missing-data, data-imputation, multiple-imputation

I have a dataset with approximately 1% of values missing completely at random.

I have thought about using the Multiple Imputation technique but I am not sure if this would be the best solution.

Can anyone please explain what the best technique is for handling missing values on a dataset as described above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is 1% missing on *any* variable -- that is, you will have 99% of your data if you just delete any observation with missing data on any variable -- and if it is truly MCAR, then you can probably just ignore it. The only loss will be a very small reduction in power.

If it is 1% on each of many variables, then, if you have a lot of variables, and the missingness is independent, then you may be missing a lot of data. In that case, I'd go with some form of multiple imputation.

Comment: Thanks so much @PeterFlom-ReinstateMonica♦!

Comment: In paragraph 2 when you say "then you may be missing a lot of data" do you mean "then if you perform listwise deletion (complete-case analysis) you may be missing a lot of data"?  Because the question already specifies that 1% of data values are missing.

Comment: @rolando2 "1% missing" is a little ambiguous. If you have 50 variables and 1% missing on each, you could be missing a lot of data. You are missing that data regardless of what analytic method you choose, although it will affect different analyses differently.